# Height of cells in different tableViews in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, row-height

In my view, i have three different tables. For first two tables, i have a fix height for each cell(e.g. say 30.0f for each cell of first table and 45.0f for each cell of second table) which i have adjusted in the storyboard according to the data in each table. For the third table, i want to have a different height for each cell. I tried the method

**(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

But the issue with this technique is that this method is called for each table. As for the first two tables, i have adjusted the height in storyboard, i don't know what to do with them.And if i do:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(tableView == myTable) {
    return 150.0;
}
}
```

As i have nothing to return for the else cases, the whole thing fails.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Assigning one `UIViewController` to more than one `UITableView` as delegate & data source is pretty bad idea as you have noticed. You can use three different `NSObject` subclass, one for each table view, all retained in your view controller. Then your problem automatically goes away.

Comment: Isn't their any way to do this without subclassing now as I have already done a lot of work, which will be more messy in case I start subclassing the tables?

Comment: No not the tables, you need unique delegate & datasource for each one of them to control them better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a height for the other tables.

If you have set there height in the storyboard you can access that height like so:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == myTable)
        return 150.0;

    return tableView.rowHeight;
}
```

tableView.rowHeight will be the height that you set in the storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You should make your view controller delegate of all 3 tableviews and in heightForRowAtIndexPath check which table called the method:

So in viewDidLoad add:

```
myTable1.delegate = self;
myTable2.delegate = self;
myTable3.delegate = self;
```

and then:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
if(tableView == myTable1) {
return 150.0;
}
else if(tableView == myTable2) {
return 75.0;
}
else if(tableView == myTable3) {
return 75.0;
}

}
```

Comment: What if i don't want to (or say i can't) set the height for myTable1 and myTable2 programatically?

Comment: If the myTable1 and myTable2 have the same row height you can just set it like this:                                                    ` - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
if(tableView == myTable1) {
return 150.0;
}
else {
return 75.0;
}

} `

Answer (score 0):

How about using the tag property?  Set the tag for each table to a unique number then return height like this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        return 150;
    }
    return 250;
}
```